# How to Access the Key of asyncStorage in another screen

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have some issue of AsyncStorage in my app,

I need to use the value of the username storage in some another screen
Now, when I login into the screen and go to the Home screen I need to get the item storage and showed them its work fine but when log out and delete the Keys
it moves me into the login screen right but when refresh the app its move me to the home screen and after 2s almost navigation me to the login screen how to do not that in the first run of the app

here my code of two screens,

#### Login screen

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  StatusBar,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  AsyncStorage
} from "react-native";
export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const login = AsyncStorage.getItem("@myApp:username");
    if (login == null) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Login");
    } else {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
    }
  }
  _onLogin = () => {
    let username = this.state.username;
    let password = this.state.password;
    if (username !== "" && password !== "") {
      AsyncStorage.setItem("@myApp:username", this.state.username).then(
        username => {
          this.setState({ username: username });
        }
      );
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
      console.log(`username is ${username}`);
    } else {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Login");
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor="#333" barStyle="light-content" />
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 28, margin: 10 }}>Login</Text>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Username"
          onChangeText={username => {
            this.setState({ username: username });
          }}
          value={this.state.username}
          autoCorrect={false}
          returnKeyType="next"
          style={{
            padding: 10,
            margin: 15,
            borderBottomColor: "#333",
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            width: "80%"
          }}
          editable={true}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Password"
          onChangeText={password => {
            this.setState({ password: password });
          }}
          secureTextEntry={true}
          value={this.state.password}
          autoCorrect={false}
          returnKeyType="next"
          style={{
            padding: 10,
            margin: 15,
            borderBottomColor: "#333",
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            width: "80%"
          }}
          editable={true}
        />

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            margin: 20,
            padding: 10,
            width: "70%",
            backgroundColor: "#1a73e8"
          }}
          onPress={this._onLogin}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: "#FFF", textAlign: "center", fontSize: 18 }}>
            Log In
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
  }
});
```

#### Home Screen

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  ImageBackground,
  Text,
  AsyncStorage,
  TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: ""
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const storedValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@myApp:username");
      this.setState({ name: storedValue });
      if (storedValue == null) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Login");
      }
      console.log(storedValue); 
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert("Error", "There was an error.");
    }
  }
  _onLogout = () => {
    AsyncStorage.removeItem("@myApp:username").then(
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Login")
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground
          source={require("./assets/bg1.jpg")}
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%"
          }}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: "center"
            }}
          >
            <Text
              style={{
                alignSelf: "center",
                backgroundColor: "#000fff",
                padding: 10,
                color: "#fff"
              }}
            >
              {`Hello, ${this.state.name} `}
            </Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{
                margin: 20,
                padding: 10,
                width: "50%",
                backgroundColor: "#1a73e8",
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignSelf: "center"
              }}
              onPress={this._onLogout}
            >
              <Text
                style={{ color: "#FFF", textAlign: "center", fontSize: 18 }}
              >
                Log out?
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a js file which will have your constants.
and then in your Constant.js file you can add your key like below:

```
 export const userNameKey= '@myApp:username';
```

and you can access that key in your screen like below:

```
import { userNameKey} from './Constants';
```

and use this as:

```
const login = AsyncStorage.getItem(userNameKey);
```